# jQuery Plugin not working in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, asp.net-mvc-4

The images which should be cycling are just sitting on top of each other. Screenshot [here](http://tinypic.com/r/343n0io/6)

In my (very simple) application I have one `View` named `Index.cshtml`. I'd like to use [jquery Cycle Plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) for this page which I have used in my PHP apps too. Below is my `_Layout.cshtml`'s relevant code

```
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render(Url.Content("~/Scripts/cycle.js")) // I added this line.
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

The plugin file `(cycle.js)` is in `Scripts` folder generated by Basic project layout.
Below is how I am using it. The following code is also in `_Layout.cshtml` (comments only here).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('test1');   //this is 'alerted'
        $('.images').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            speed: 2000
        });
        alert('test2!'); //this is NOT 'alerted'
    });
</script>
```

When I view the source after requesting page in a browser, I get this :

```
<title>Asp.Net MVC 4 Hello World App</title>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/cycle.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('test1'); 
        $('.images').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            speed: 2000
        });
        alert('test12');
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
...
</html>
```

Here is the container for images:

```
        <div class="images" id="images">
            <img src="@Url.Content("../Images/image1.jpg")" alt="page image" />
            <img src="@Url.Content("../Images/image2.jpg")" alt="page image" />
            <img src="@Url.Content("../Images/image3.jpg")" alt="page image" />
            <img src="@Url.Content("../Images/image4.jpg")" alt="page image" />
        </div>
```

The files are therefore successfully being loaded. I believe the issue is how `$(document).ready()` works. because whatever code I put before `.cycle()` works but nothing works after it.

Comment: can you please look at your browser console for any javascript error?

Comment: Firebug gives me this: `TypeError: $(".images").cycle is not a function`

Comment: Can you verify that the cycle.js file is loaded? In IE press `F12`, open the Scripts tab and open the dropdown next to the `start debugging` button and check if you see it and can access it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I can access the file. However IE's console says `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'cycle'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem after some (more) searching. Somehow jquery was being loaded twice. Once before cycle plugin file and the other one after it. [This link](http://drupal.org/node/633188) helped to catch the problem, specifically `redndahead`'s comment.

I opened Firebug console and observed that indeed jQuery was being loaded twice. I removed the following line from `_Layout.cshtml` page under `<body>` tag and now the plugin is working fine.

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

[This SO quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944363/usage-of-the-asp-net-mvc4-jquery-javascript-bundles) is very helpful for those wondering what `bundles` are. Thanks to all for their response.

Answer (score 0):

That might have several reasons but the most common solution in many cases is:
carrying the

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

if you know turkish you can check this article for more information

http://ogrenmeliyim.com/mvc-4-de-jquery-tanimlanmasi/

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script 

 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">

</script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("p").click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>When you click on this paragraph , it will hide.</p>


</body>
</html>
```