# MVC 4 - Script/Css Rendering Problems

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I get the following error mesasges in my browser console:

> GET http://*:54559/Scripts/ 403 (Forbidden)
>
> http://*:54559/Content/css/* 400 (Bad Request)
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

In my _Layout.shtml I use the following code to try and include css/bootstrap.

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css/*")

<!-- JavaScript -->
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

<script>
    // Activates the Carousel
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000
    })
</script>
```

The file paths look ok as in my project the css is located at "Content/css" and scripts is just a folder at the top level called "Scripts"

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you added the scripts in BundleConfig.cs?

Comment: no dont have any bundles

Comment: Follow the link included in Chris' answer. You need to create a bundle and then @Scripts.Render will include those scripts which are added to the bundle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`~/Content/css/` and `~/Scripts/` aren't file paths. They are bundle names, so if you don't have a Bundle file follow these steps:

In your `App_Start` folder add a `BundleConfig` Class:

```
 public class BundleConfig
 {

 }
```

Add a `RegisterBundles` method like this:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{

}
```

Then you can add a bundle, write this code into your method:

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));
```

Here `~/Content/css` is your **Bundle Name** and `~/Content/site.css` is your Css File Path.Change it if your css file in a different path.

Now there is one more step, open your `Global.asax` file and add this code into your `Application_Start` :

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

Then you can render your Bundle with:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

And also you can render more than one file with one bundle, to do this add your all file paths here like this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
.Include("~/Content/site.css",
         "~/Content/sample.css",
         "~/Content/sample2.css"));
```

PS: Also you can take a look at this question about benefits of using Bundles: [Usage of the ASP.NET MVC4 jquery/javascript bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944363/usage-of-the-asp-net-mvc4-jquery-javascript-bundles)

Answer (score 2):

MVC is looking for `Bundles`, which are lists of the scripts and CSS files you want to use in your site.

Check out your bundle registration file at `App_Start\BundleConfig.cs`

Ensure your bundle names correspond to what you are passing into `Scripts` and `Styles`.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Comment: Ahh i dont even have a bundleconfig.cs file

Comment: Now you have an opportunity to learn about bundles, then :) They're all kinds of awesome sauce!