# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function for datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am working in ASP .NET MVC4. When jquery is loaded then I got an error `Undefined is not a function` by using jquery. 
[image]

In HTML version its working correctly but when it loaded through compiler it is not working correctly.

Comment: Are you sure that the plugin is being loaded?

Comment: yes plugin jquery.dataTable.js is loaded

Comment: maybe it's `datatable` and not `dataTable`?

Comment: Can you link to the site?

Comment: I tried both datatable and dataTable but same error

Comment: sorry it is on my localhost

Comment: What order are the `<script>` tags to load things in? You need to make sure jQuery is before the plugin script.

Comment: Sir order of jquery libraries is also in correct sequence

Comment: "yes plugin jquery.dataTable.js is loaded" - how do you know? show the `script` tag that loads it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I am answering my own question I got error for this question it is just rearranging file sequence in file loading Thanks to all who give me time to solve my problem

Comment: Could you post the order ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is constructor `DataTable()`, It is supposed to be capitalized.
Instead of `$('#dt_inbox').dataTable()` use `$('#dt_inbox').DataTable()`

Answer (score 0):

You problably forgot to add the plugin to your bundle.  The following questions goes into more details:

[Usage of the ASP.NET MVC4 jquery/javascript bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944363/usage-of-the-asp-net-mvc4-jquery-javascript-bundles)

Comment: Thanks for giving me your time. I also tried bundle method but nothing happen good. please can u contact with me please

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem for hours.. My issue was resolved when I changed the `$` to `jQuery` in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are using AMD pattern, you would need to keep your module name to "datatables" so that you don't get "Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).DataTable is not a function"

Below link was helpful.
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21178/amd-definition-without-explicit-module-name