# Basics of Bundls & Bundle-ordering CSS and JavaScript /

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I am new to MVC, as I try to learn (while doing things in the most professional way), I am staring with Empty `MVC4` template.

Speaking not only for my self I assume:

**could anyone be real kind to walk through the implementation from ground zero, step by step?**

So now, that I remembered reading somewhere about the technique of declaring a folder for the scripts instead of specifying each, I had to implement it my self, meaning I estimate every new thing (it's pros and cons) then I decide if I am using it, that is why I start an Empty project.

So I start to learn how to implement it correctly, and I read about the **order issue** and I read some more scattered information but I could not see clear instructions on where and when to put it all and which one of the examples of implementation should I use:

First where do I create this? (just place it within a .Cs file within `App_Start`?

```
//so only cause it's there it will be invoked ? (...same as windows Run ?)
public static class BundleConfig
{

    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                     "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                     "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
    }
}
```

In the code above `Add new sb("  -->    ~/bundles < -` is it a variable or physical folder

Do I need to implement the `{version}` parameter/variable

And last, what is the correct or top notch approach for ordering?

Where in relation to the project and to each other (bundle vs ordering) it is placed?

I have mentioned the issue of ordering so I could better understand so I could properly implement the code, I have tried to understand from such answers as @Kayees pointed out, but It's not talking on some important steps as to where to place the code within solution and as @LoneXcoder pointed out `Bundle-ordering`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of the ASP.NET MVC4 jquery/javascript bundles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944363/usage-of-the-asp-net-mvc4-jquery-javascript-bundles)

Comment: @kayess not really , as it is not covering order for instance..

Comment: Whatever, it's a perfect too broad question and has sort of canonical dupes whose already answered like [ordering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979718/how-can-i-specify-an-explicit-scriptbundle-include-order), want more? Use search..

Comment: @kayess I didn't only search but had a little research . thanks for being understanding

Comment: @kayess i have installed this :http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/the-name-scripts-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context/